# How to run sprite sheet frame by frame in flutter flame?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flame

I wrote a code to play a sprite sheet frame by frame, but unfortunately, it's not playing correctly. It's moving to the right side. The sprites on the sprite sheet are dancing sprites, so when played frame by frame, it should show like an dancing animation video. I hope you understand what I mean . If you know how to resolve this issue and play the sprite sheet frame by frame, help me. Actually, I have no idea what the error is with the sprite sheet or code.

code

```
class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
    super.initState();
  }
  late double width, height;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double aspectRatio = screenSize.height / screenSize.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: aspectRatio,
        child: GameWidget(
          game: Game(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Game extends FlameGame {
  BuildContext context;

  Game(this.context);

  SpriteAnimationComponent animationComponent1 =
  SpriteAnimationComponent(size: Vector2(840, 440));


  @override
  Color backgroundColor() => const Color(0xFFFFC107);

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    await loadAnimations();
    add(animationComponent1);

    animationComponent1.position = Vector2(1, 1);

  }

  Future<void> loadAnimations() async {
    SpriteSheet spriteSheet =
    SpriteSheet(image: await images.load('spritesheet.png'),  srcSize: Vector2(1226, 1226));
    SpriteAnimation spriteAnimation =
    spriteSheet.createAnimation(row: 0, stepTime: 0.7, from: 5, to: 24);

    animationComponent1.animation = spriteAnimation;
  }
}
```

sprite sheet image url

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1obZBPhgn2UMhaBvXBvW3dkg7I02a2ksJ/view?usp=sharing
```

screenshot of UI
[image]

**update code video url**

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y6gm77-OkLkeJTpv9AGE1sgodqANO_nl/view?usp=share_link
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
        super.initState();
      }
      late double width, height;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        double aspectRatio = screenSize.height / screenSize.width;
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          body: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: aspectRatio,
            child: GameWidget(
              game: Game(context,screenSize),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Game extends FlameGame {
  BuildContext context;
  Size screenSize;
  Game(this.context, this.screenSize);

  SpriteAnimationComponent animationComponent1 =
      SpriteAnimationComponent(size: Vector2(840, 440));

  @override
  Color backgroundColor() => const Color(0xFFFFC107);

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    await loadAnimations();
    add(animationComponent1);
//new code
    animationComponent1.position = Vector2(
      screenSize.width / 2 - animationComponent1.size.x / 2,
      screenSize.height / 2 - animationComponent1.size.y / 2,
    );
  }

  Future<void> loadAnimations() async {
    SpriteSheet spriteSheet = SpriteSheet(
        image: await images.load('spritesheet.png'),
        srcSize: Vector2(1226, 1226));
    SpriteAnimation spriteAnimation =
        spriteSheet.createAnimation(row: 0, stepTime: 0.7, from: 5, to: 24);

    animationComponent1.animation = spriteAnimation;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support!!! I made the changes you suggested, but the issue is still the same. Also, I have included an updated question running video in my question.

Comment: I modified the code, please try again

Comment: The code is working, but the sprite sheet frames are not running in their specific places. Instead, they are running in different places on the screen, which makes it look like a slideshow from left to right. Do you think this is a problem with the sprite sheet or is the sprite sheet correct?

Comment: "For example, I want to place the child who is wearing green clothes at the center of the screen. To do this, I need to ensure that when the whole image is centered, the child will be automatically centered as well. I want the frames to run in specific places on the screen.